# C++ each class depends on the second one

Tags: c++

Let's say I have two classes:

```
class One {
    Two *somevar = new Two;
    // (...)
};

class Two {
    One *somevar = new One;
    // (...)
}
```

And it's impossible to compile something like that. How to handle it?

Comment: @bta has the correct answer - all that you need is forward declaration. However, this sort of "mutual embrace" is always a code smell to me. I am not saying that there are never cases when this is right, but what I am saying is that, in my personal experience, whenever I encounter such a situation it means that I have not carefully thought out my class structure. By restructuring the classes, the problem usually goes away. Have you considered that what you have is not a coding problem bur, rather, a design problem?

Answer (score 9):

Since all that you are nesting is a pointer, try:

```
class Two;

class One {
    Two *somevar = new Two;
    // (...)
};

class Two {
    One *somevar = new One;
    // (...)
}
```

By forward-declaring class `Two`, you are giving the compiler enough information to be able to create the pointer inside class `One`.  If you were trying to nest the classes themselves and not just pointers, then there would not be any way to solve the problem.

Comment: +1. Also in this kind of pseudo-code, the initialization of someVar need to occur in a cpp file including the appropriate headers so that the full class definition is available (required for operator new).

Comment: @stinky472, @bta, it's possible to do this header-only, but you'd have to have to have the initialization done in the constructor, defined externally from the declaration. The constructor (make sure you mark it inline) for `One` would have to occur after the definition of `Two.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution:

```
// class Type instead of Type
// so:
class Two *somevar = new class Two;
```